# Can SharePoint link to a bookmark/anchor within a word/pdf document?

Tags: document, hyperlink, word, pdf, anchor-tags

I understand linking to bookmarks internally within a document works within both PDF and Word files however is it possible to link to these bookmarks from outside of the document?

Ideally this would work similarly to how HTML pages can link to sections of other HTML pages using tags (i.e. href="http://www.example.com/some-page.html#exactline")

Any help would be very much appreciated as I have been unable to find any documentation regarding this, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of MS-Word having support for this, but if your PDF contains so called 'named destinations' (not just PDF bookmarks although they may both the present) then you can specify the 'named destination' on the URL.

```
http://SomeWebApp/SomeDocLib/somepdf.pdf#nameddest=TOC
```

You can also directly link to page numbers

```
http://SomeWebApp/SomeDocLib/somepdf.pdf#page=3
```

Your system's PDF Viewer needs to support this syntax, but I am pretty sure they all do.

Blameless plug and disclaimer: The upcoming version (8.3) of the PDF Converter for SharePoint, a product that I work on, automatically converts PDF Bookmarks to named destinations. Let me know if you would like to participate in the beta.

Comment: your to-page link doesn't work, see [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408839/url-to-a-particular-section-page-in-a-word-document)

Comment: My answer was talking about PDF, your link talks about MS-Word. Glad that you found a solution.

Comment: yep, the question is about both (word+pdf) so I thought your answer addresses both. Anyway thanks for your efforts!